# Azure AD authentication with asp.net Identity for authorisation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory

I tried to look for all over internet but couldn't see how I can achieve what I was asked to. Here is my enterprise app which uses Asp.net Identity for form based authentication. I had extended User and Role along with Groups to provide authorization in my code. (note: not using any group/role directives).

Now I was asked to look at possibility of changing code to accommodate Azure Active Directory authentication. I tried reading on how you can register app, send user to Azure site for authentication, get back token etc. However I'm stuck at 'what-afterwards?' I have authenticated user How can I use my existing Asp.net Identity model where user was stored in sql database. How to use this token to relate the existing user.

Moreover, when I change my project to allow Azure AD, it removes Aspnet.Identity package as its not compatible with Azure AD !!

I even tried manually keeping both packages side by side, I got to point where user is sent to authenticate on Azure, diverted back to home page and again to login on Azure AD in never ending loop.

to summarize the question, How can I authenticate user from AAD and keep using existing Roles and groups authorization.

**Edit:** 
I tried creating separate web service which will authenticate user and send JWT token. which works find if I call it directly on browser, however, when I tried to call this service from my web app I get weird error

```
 Application with identifier 'a2d2---------------' was not found in the directory azurewebsites.net
```

Weird part here is name of directory is 'azurewebsites.net' and not the default directory I'm using.

**Update**
Here is code which throws error

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
        {


            try
            {

                // get the access token
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new TokenCache());

                var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, password);
//Error on below line
                AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientCredential);


                // give it to the server to get a JWT
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
......
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant- 
         Id}/oauth2/v2.0/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);         
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");         
request.AddHeader("grant_type", "password");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        "grant_type=password&client_id={client-Id}&client_secret={client- 
        secret}&scope={scopeurl}&userName={username}&password={password}", 
        ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var json = response.Content;
var JSONObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var token = (string)JSONObject["access_token"];
```

Comment: This needs way more details. What is `RestClient` ? Where to find it ? Why use this instead of `HttpClient` ? This answer also looks a lot less cleaner that the code in the question itself.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue so I created an Office 365 owin security plugin. I shared the code on github. It's based on the [katana project](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) at codeplex.

You can find the source code at https://github.com/chadwjames/wakizashi.

You will need to register your application [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/). When registering the application set the call back uri to https://yourdomain/signin-office365

The Application ID is your Client Id and the Password is your Client Secret.

Once you have it registered you can modify the Startup.Auth.cs and add something like this to the ConfigureAuth method.

```
        //setup office 365
        var office365Options = new Office365AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ada:ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ada:ClientSecret"],
            Provider = new Office365AuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async context =>
                {
                    await
                        Task.Run(
                            () => context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Office365AccessToken", context.AccessToken)));
                }
            },
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie
        };

        office365Options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        app.UseOffice365Authentication(office365Options);
```

When I have more time I hope to create a nuget package for this.