# Replace claims identity with Forms Identity

Tags: azure-active-directory, forms-authentication, claims-based-identity

I am using AAD authentication for the application but this is temporary till the time my user is getting authenticated and redirected back to my application once it came on my application i am getting

```
this.User.Identity  as ClaimsIdentity
```

But i dont want claims identity once user came back i want to change/Replace this claims identity with Forms Identity.

I tried to set forms authentication cookie but when user redirected and come back still identity is claims only it is not getting change to forms identity.

tried with authenticating claims identity with expire date but still cookies are flowing and i am getting claims identity.

```
var virtualUserClaims = context.User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
                        virtualUserClaims.RemoveClaim(virtualUserClaims.FindFirst(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name));
                        virtualUserClaims.AddClaim(new Claim(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, firstFullUsernameToAuthenticatedAgainst));
                        var authenticationManager = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
                        authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant =
                        new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(virtualUserClaims), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true , ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1) });
```

After this code i am setting forms authentication cookie

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(firstFullUsernameToAuthenticatedAgainst, false);
```

Can anyone tell me how i will remove claims identity

Comment: Have you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120051/azure-ad-authentication-with-asp-net-identity-for-authorisation

Comment: how it will help me?